# numpy typing: specifying only some dimensions of the array?

Tags: python, numpy, typing

Here is the documentation of numpy typing:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html#module-numpy.typing

For example, I would like to specify a type to be an array of size (any,3).

The following:

```
Trajectory = npt.NDArray[(typing.Any, 3), np.float32]
```

has mypy complaining:

> error: The type "Type[ndarray[Any, Any]]" is not generic and not indexable

I could not find a proper way of doing this. Or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify size with numpy typing, only the type of the array:

`Trajectory = npt.NDArray[np.float32]`

When creating your array you can use this type like this (for example): `arr: Trajectory = np.array(my_trajectory_list)`.

Specifying shape can be done like this:

`arr: Trajectory = np.empty(shape=(input_length, 3))`

But you cannot set the length to `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't explore numpy typing, but I'd do this with int type alias:

```
NSamples = int
ThreeFeatures = int  # = 3
ArrayOf3Features = np.ndarray[(NSamples, ThreeFeatures), float]
```

or just `np.ndarray[(int, int), float]` if you prefer less verbosity.